# Как динамически создать гиперссылку (на Golang)?

Tags: golang

Как программно создать ссылку?

Не выходит приклеить GET-запрос к тексту ссылки (в `href`). Пробую так (другие функции форматирования тоже пробовал):

```
<br>
var tokenString = string(hashLink)
<br>
var dataRespon = fmt.Sprintf("Данные сохранены. Нажмите <a 
href=\"https://site.com/Link?%d\">ссылку</a>.", tokenString)
```

Или так:

```
<br>
var myLink = "https://site.com/Link?"
<br>
var tokenString = string(hashLink)
<br>
var dataRespon = fmt.Sprintf("Данные сохранены. Нажмите <a href=\"%d%d\">ссылку</a>.", myLink, tokenString)
```

В итоге хочу получить ссылку типа:

```
<a href="https://site.com/Link?$2a$10$Xj10hPlP0n9bWfql3P/oz">ссылку</a>
```

оно же: `https://site.com/Link?$2a$10$Xj10hPlP0n9bWfql3P/oz`

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть в документацию на [Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) то станет очевидно, что для обработки строки нужно использовать `%s`. Вы же используете `%d`, что используется для вывода числа.

Поэтому либо вот так

```
var tokenString = string(hashLink)
var dataRespon = fmt.Sprintf("Данные сохранены. Нажмите <a href=\"https://site.com/Link?%s\">ссылку</a>.", tokenString)
```

или

```
var myLink = "https://site.com/Link?"
var tokenString = string(hashLink)
var dataRespon = fmt.Sprintf("Данные сохранены. Нажмите <a href=\"%s%s\">ссылку</a>.", myLink, tokenString)
```

правда, мой ответ базируется на том, что tokenString содержит правильную строку.

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже решил. Проблема была в этом операторе. )

Answer (score 0):

Ответ @KoVadim, конечно, работает. И в некоторых
ситуациях, возможно, даже вполне достаточен. Но если вы хотите
избежать опечаток и максимально обезопасить себя от различного рода
инъекций кода, используйте более структурированный
подход. Для создания *URL* есть
пакет [`net/url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url#URL):

```golang
var link = &url.URL{
	Scheme:   "https",
	Host:     "site.com",
	Path:     "/Link",
	RawQuery: "$2a$10$Xj10hPlP0n9bWfql3P/oz",
}
```

Для безопасной работы же с *HTML*-шаблонами есть
[`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template#Template)
(не путать с `text/template`; путаница ужасная, увы):

```golang
const page = `Данные сохранены.  Нажмите <a href="{{ .Link }}">ссылку</a>.` + "\n"

var tpl *template.Template
tpl, err = template.New("main").Parse(page)
// Check err.

type resp struct {
	Link *url.URL
}

var r = &resp{
	Link: link,
}

err = tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, r)
// Check err.
```

[Пример целиком](https://play.golang.org/p/iwXd4053WgU).

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)